# How can I stop the webcraping loop in Python when it hit the page that I want to scrape?

Tags: python, while-loop

[image]I am writing code for webscraping, and I am trying to gather the webpage that requires me to keep clicking "the more" button. So, I finished code and ran it.

However, it goes **endless**. I want the loop to be **stopped** when it reached the last page that I want to scrape, which is **530**.

This is the code below. Let me know where I should put the break inside.

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from tqdm import tqdm
import pandas as pd
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    
def get_articles(last_page):
    url = "https://www.jimin.jp/news/?more=25"
    driver.get(url) 
    aricle_xpath = "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[4]/div/div"
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
    element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, aricle_xpath)))

    pre = -1
    scrollHeight = 500
    interval = 500    
    retry = 0
    total_retry = 5
    articles = []

    # main loop to get all articles 
    while not driver.current_url.endswith(f"more={last_page}"): 
        # sub loop to check if all articles in the current page are loaded
        while pre != len(articles) and retry != total_retry: 
            pre = len(articles)    
            driver.execute_script(f"window.scrollTo(0, {scrollHeight});")
            scrollHeight += interval    
            articles = driver.find_elements("xpath", aricle_xpath)    
            time.sleep(1.5)
            retry += 1
        pre = -1
        retry = 0
        more_button_xpath = (
            "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[5]/div/a"
        )
        driver.find_element("xpath", more_button_xpath).click()
        time.sleep(1.5)    
        print(f"Collected articles: {len(articles)}", end="\r")

    # After fetching all articles, now retrieve the urls
    articles = driver.find_elements("xpath", aricle_xpath) 

    # xpath relative to the article's xpath
    link_xpath = "./div/a"
    urls = []
    for article in articles:
        urls.append(article.find_element("xpath", link_xpath).get_attribute("href"))

    return urls

def get_article_data(url):
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(1)    
    date_xpath = "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div"
    body_xpath = "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]"    
    date = driver.find_element("xpath", date_xpath).text
    body = driver.find_element("xpath", body_xpath).text    
    return date, body

last_page = 530    
urls = get_articles(last_page) ##this is where the error occurs. 

data = []
for url in tqdm(urls):
    if url.startswith("https://www.jimin.jp/news/information/"):
        get_article_data(url)
        data.append(get_article_data(url))
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I think your `while` condition should work. Have you tried printing `driver.current_url` in the loop to see what it looks like when it goes past the end?

Comment: It does not let me see the results, because simply the loop is endless and not stop any point for hours and hours.

Comment: I could not reproduce your error, your code does't even find 'element' in the beginning in my tentative.

Comment: @RifloSnake: I added the error above. It is not technically an error, but just does not stop the loop process. It hit the highest number then restart from the start

Comment: I'm willing to help, bur you should understand that without posting a minimal, reproducible example of your code that allows us to try and test it for ourselves, it is much harder to find a solution. Thank you Julia.

Comment: Also, adding print statements to check what the code is actually doing is very helpful. Add as many prints in key parts of your code, one I would personally add is, print(driver.current_url.endswith(f"more={last_page}")) right below the first while loop, to actually check if the output becomes True when it hits 530. If it doesn't, then the boolean check is incorrect. If it does, you code logic is flawed in some other place.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a different approach, but you can get all the data in json from the page fetch request. I found it in the developer tools' network tab.

https://www.jimin.jp/news/data/2022_all.json?v=1677797490298

I hope this is what you needed.